# Using Teams Toolkit with an existing AAD App Registration

Tags: teams-toolkit

In my organization, developers do not have authority to create Azure AD app registrations. However, the domain admins have created and provided a registration for me. Via the Teams app toolkit (via VS or VS Code), I cannot find a method for specifying the existing Azure AD app registration information and proceed with local debugging in Teams successfully. I'm new to development via the toolkit, so I'm attempting to simply debug the Tab HelloWorld app.

I tried creating a Teams App via the Developer Portal in Teams and using the Teams App Id, as well as the existing Azure AD App Id, to update the local manifest of the HelloWorld app and attempt to debug locally. VS opens the Teams web app, but Teams--nor the Helloworld app--load.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this [tutorial](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/wiki/Using-existing-Azure-AD-app-in-TeamsFx-project).

Teams Toolkit will use your input Azure AD app if you input the necessary info in `.fx/configs/config.{env}.json`, and will try to update your Azure AD app. If update failed, Teams Toolkit will show some warnings and you need to follow these steps to manually update your Azure AD app.

Comment: Thank you! Would this be necessary for an application which is running locally? I was able to get the HelloWorld Tab app running locally, via my personal test tenant. I checked the conf.local.json, and none of the AAD config mentioned in the documentation is specified.

Comment: At this point, in my enterprise tenant, local debugging leads to a the web browser navigating to the "launchUrl" defined in `launchSettings.json` but only the Teams icon is displayed.

Comment: The following issue was opened for further insight as well: https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/issues/6766

Comment: @Debro012 Teams Toolkit will create an Azure AD app if you did not specify your AAD config and save in `state.{env}.json`.
From your screenshot in the issue, the browser seems still loading Teams and your Teams app is still not activated. Please wait for a while or close the browser and run local debug again. If this still cannot work, you can try the steps below to unblock yourself: 1. Run `local debug` 2. Trigger command `Zip Teams metadata package` from Treeview 3. Open Teams in Browser or Desktop, and install the app: `${your-project-path}/build/appPackage/appPackage.local.zip`